# If an exe is referring to a dll then how sould the dll be added ? should it be registered or should it be added to the bin folder?

Tags: .net, exe, registration

I have a .net exe which is referring to another .net assembly.My question is during deployment should we register the assembly using REGASM or should we just copy the dll into the Bin folder of the exe code? I am a beginner at this so please excuse me if I have mixed up the terminologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use REGASM. That is for registering COM DLLs.

The easiest way to include the reference is to include it in the folder.

The other option you have, if you're going to be sharing that referenced DLL among multiple projects, is to register it in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).